# Can we correlate Facebook Likes with locally registered users?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Users on our site can register an account with us.

If a logged in user Likes us on Facebook, is it possible to note this so we can track the user?  Maybe we could log IP addresses?

Comment: Even if you could, tracking people by IP is very unreliable. Most people have dynamic IPs, not to mention WiFi networks and so on.

Comment: So is there any other way exist to track that information.?

Comment: Check @Pooya's answer, but instead of saving IP you could add a cookie or if the user is logged in the site you could make ajax request and save that he liked your site on Facebook.

Answer (score 3):

you can do it  check this link up
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/
you can know when user liked a link so then you can use jQuery to save user IP

Comment: why you are saving ip when you want to track Logged users ?!
you can save Liked Post id & user id together in database

Answer (score 0):

Not happening. It's a breech of privacy and Facebook will never allow it.